# Sencha Touch 2.1: Allowing horizontal overflow on a vertical list

Tags: list, sencha-touch, touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to create a List in Sencha Touch 2.1 which has horizontal overflow per itemTPL line.  It is still a vertical list, but has too much content to show per line.

So I placed the list in a wrapper Container, which has a set width and allows horizontal scrolling.  This allows the header and list content to move horizontally.  It practically works.  However, after the scroll is released it snaps back to 0.  Also the scrollbar is visibly too large for the container viewport giving the sense that this is not rendered correctly.

Does anyone know how to allow the top Container to freely scroll.

A sample is here, which shows the icons overflowing the small window.  You can scroll over to see the full icon but cannot leave the scroller in place...
http://www.senchafiddle.com/#dSMpw

```
Ext.application({
name: 'SenchaFiddle',
models:['Model'],
stores:['Store'],

launch: function() {
    var list = Ext.create('Ext.List',{
        store: 'Store',
        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<img src="{icon}" width=750 height=50/>'),
        flex:1
    });

    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        layout:'vbox',
        width:750,
                    scrollable : {
                        direction     : 'horizontal',
                        directionLock : true
                    },
        items: [
            {
                html: 'Header bar',
            },
            list
        ]
    });

    Ext.Viewport.add(panel)
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

been searching for this but apparently we can't achieve this,
the rule is:

- if you want to display item horizontally use dataview
- if you want to display item vertically use list
- if you need to group items then use list

as for the proposed [answer](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/examples/list-horizontal/) given by [Ram G Atherya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651689/ram-g-athreya),

if we look at the source code, its using dataview and not list (xtype: 'dataview')
and the "inline: wrap: false" make the item scroll horizontally and not being wrapped to next line..

Answer (score 0):

i dont entirely understand your question but i think [this](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/examples/list-horizontal/) is what you want...
All you need to do is set the list's inline wrap as false

```
inline: {
        wrap: false
},
```